# don't add my files in xap file (phonegap)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, cordova

I don't add files in xap file built visual studio in phonegap project.

Noticed that js files are added. But, for example, images do not show (adding all folders)

What do I do?

Comment: css files and cordova.png also sees

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the relevant file entries to `ManifestProcessor.js`?

Comment: ManufestProcessor.js - standard file. I found small solution:
(Russian foul language, Russian foul language, Russian foul language).
This VS 2010 (Russian obscenities), add files with atributes: Resoures, but file BuildManifestProcessor.js parses Content links! 
(Russian foul language) (Russian foul language) (Russian foul language)!
Make properties from files and Build Action: Content.

I do not know why the Resourse files were not added in *.csproj!

Answer (score 0):

This VS 2010, add files with atributes: Resoures, but file BuildManifestProcessor.js parses Content links. Make properties from files and Build Action: Content.

I do not know why the Resourse files were not added in *.csproj.

Comment: BuildManifestProcessor.js parses Content and Resourse link:
    <code>nodes = projXml.selectNodes("/Project/ItemGroup/Resource/Link");
    WScript.Echo("/Project/ItemGroup/Resource/Link nodes.length" + nodes.length);</code>